# PNG output using LaTeX

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a way to use `LaTeX` symbols in `gnuplot` and obtain the plot directly as a `.png` with desired the resolution? I would also love to have the immediate preview of the plot as it comes with the `qt` terminal which I've been using. I've attached a screenshot of what I mean by the preview.

I've checked out the `epslatex` terminal but I don't get an immediate preview plus a direct `.png`.

[image: Screenshot showing "immediate preview"]

I'm using MacOS.

Edit: The output doesn't matter. I would like to see the preview with the `epslatex` terminal.

Comment: Welcome ! I wonder why you want to use LaTeX to render a raster ouptut ?

Comment: Hi. I would like to use the LaTeX symbols in the plot, but not necessarily create a LaTeX file for it since the reports I'm going to submit will be handwritten. I know I can convert the LaTeX file with only the plots and print it, and thats hardly an issue, but I primarily would like to see the preview of the plot.

Comment: I am sorry, but your question still does not make sense to me. If you do not intend to print the picture anyway, how is the output file format or the viewer of any importance ?

Comment: I've included an edit statement in the question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: My previous comment takes your edit into account. What I mean is why would you like to get a png **from** a LaTeX file. Isn't an eps or a pdf ok for you ? Otherwise, if you only want a png, why use a LaTeX file ?

Comment: Oh right. With respect to the earlier comment, I meant that I could use the plot in LaTeX and generate a PDF, which I'll be printing. So yeah, the output doesn't matter. What I would like is the preview that comes along with the qt terminal in the epslatex terminal.

The thing is, earlier I used to get my PNGs and paste them on Pages (Word) and print it. But this doesn;t incorporate LaTeX symbols in it.

Comment: Okay, I just realised that the "preview" I was referring to is a part of so called interactive terminals and qt is one of them. Apparently epslatex is not, and hence I won't be able to interact with the plot. Thanks for the help.